# How to provide data to react with drf without extra requests?

Tags: reactjs, django, rest, django-rest-framework, single-page-application

I build a single page application with react and django rest framework. I want to have an ability to change "static" info through django admin interface to avoid unnecessary extra deploy every time. Such info like background image and text from about section.

To edit it I create `cms` django app and register models in admin.

To serve frontend in production I use `TemplateView` from `django.views.generic` package. It serves html file from bundled react app directory. here's part of root urls.py:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    # ...
    # api endpoints here
    # ...
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
urlpatterns += [re_path(r'^.*', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html'))]
```

to serve it in development I use `react-scripts start` from `create-react-app`

How can I pass information like the current url of the background image, text for about section, etc. there?

Simple option is to create bunch of views to get this info and request all the data from react app, but I don't really like this approach.

another option is to redefine TemplateView like this

```py
from django.views import generic


class TemplateView(generic.TemplateView):
    template_name = 'index.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context_data = dict()
        # get all data from db here
        return context_data
```

But how then I use this in react app? in production and in development.

I believe there should be correct way to solve such problem.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution I found is to hardcode url to background image on frontend and create or update symlink corresponding to this url.
So when I upload new image on django admin, behind scene it saves record in the database, save file itself and update symlink. In this way I also able to set another image as active just updating symlink in process of saving.
This solution looks good for me, but only works for static files, not text data.